# Calculate one lag differences in R

Tags: r

Data:

```
d <- data.frame(year= c(1,2,5,6,1,2,7),id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2),value=1:7)

year id value
1    1   1
2    1   2
5    1   3
6    1   4
1    2   5
2    2   6
7    2   7
```

Desired output:

```
year id value
1    1   NA
2    1   1
5    1   NA
6    1   1
1    2   NA
2    2   1
7    2   NA
```

Basically, I want the one lag differences of value within the same id, if not available then missing. The difficulty is that the available years in each id is basically random, so I am not quite sure the bast way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a grouping variable and then do the one lag

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id, grp = as.integer(gl(nrow(df1), 2, nrow(df1)))) %>%
   mutate(diff = lag(value))
```